# Error conexion Firebase Android

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

estoy enviando los datos de mi app a fire base pero cuando lo hago me sale el siguiente mensaje:

05-30 17:59:57.410 2757-2757/bolivar.andres.app.andresbolivar.com.miapplocal I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config
05-30 17:59:57.587 2757-3418/bolivar.andres.app.andresbolivar.com.miapplocal W/RepoOperation: setValue at /BD/-LDnGs5W0HjrGHeesA2O failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

Los permisos ya los di en el manifest, agregue los diferentes componentes en el Gradle y el error persiste[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

MAINACTIVITY

package bolivar.andres.app.andresbolivar.com.miapplocal;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button SubmitButton;
Button mapa;
ImageView imagenlocal;

EditText ed_local;
EditText ed_direccion;
EditText ed_tel;
EditText ed_longitud;
EditText ed_latitud;



public static final String Firebase_Server_URL = "https://neighbors-856b4.firebaseio.com/";

String localHolder, direccionHolder, telHolder, longitudHolder, latitudHolder;

Firebase firebase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;

public static final String Database_Path = "BD";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(MainActivity.this);

    firebase = new Firebase(Firebase_Server_URL);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Database_Path);

    SubmitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);

    ed_local = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tx_local);
    ed_direccion = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tx_direccion);
    ed_tel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tx_tel);
    ed_longitud = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tx_longitud);
    ed_latitud = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tx_latitud);
    mapa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_mapa);
    imagenlocal = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mapa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_mapa);

    //mapa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    SubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
```

try {

```
//startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class));
StudentDetails studentDetails = new StudentDetails();
GetDataFromEditText();

studentDetails.setStudentDireccion(localHolder);
studentDetails.setStudentDireccion(direccionHolder);
studentDetails.setStudentTel(telHolder);
studentDetails.setStudentLongitud(longitudHolder);
studentDetails.setStudentLatitud(latitudHolder);

String StudentRecordIDFromServer = databaseReference.push().getKey();
databaseReference.child(StudentRecordIDFromServer).setValue(studentDetails);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Datos guardados", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();

}

```
        }
    });
}

private void GetDataFromEditText() {


    localHolder = ed_local.getText().toString().trim();
    direccionHolder = ed_direccion.getText().toString().trim();
    telHolder = ed_tel.getText().toString().trim();
    longitudHolder = ed_longitud.getText().toString().trim();
    latitudHolder = ed_latitud.getText().toString().trim();

}
```

}

GRADLE
package bolivar.andres.app.andresbolivar.com.miapplocal;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button SubmitButton;
Button mapa;
ImageView imagenlocal;

EditText ed_local;
EditText ed_direccion;
EditText ed_tel;
EditText ed_longitud;
EditText ed_latitud;



public static final String Firebase_Server_URL = "https://neighbors-856b4.firebaseio.com/";

String localHolder, direccionHolder, telHolder, longitudHolder, latitudHolder;

Firebase firebase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;

public static final String Database_Path = "BD";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(MainActivity.this);

    firebase = new Firebase(Firebase_Server_URL);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Database_Path);

    SubmitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);

    ed_local = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tx_local);
    ed_direccion = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tx_direccion);
    ed_tel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tx_tel);
    ed_longitud = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tx_longitud);
    ed_latitud = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tx_latitud);
    mapa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_mapa);
    imagenlocal = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mapa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_mapa);

    //mapa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    SubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
```

try {

```
//startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class));
StudentDetails studentDetails = new StudentDetails();
GetDataFromEditText();

studentDetails.setStudentDireccion(localHolder);
studentDetails.setStudentDireccion(direccionHolder);
studentDetails.setStudentTel(telHolder);
studentDetails.setStudentLongitud(longitudHolder);
studentDetails.setStudentLatitud(latitudHolder);

String StudentRecordIDFromServer = databaseReference.push().getKey();
databaseReference.child(StudentRecordIDFromServer).setValue(studentDetails);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Datos guardados", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();

}

```
        }
    });
}

private void GetDataFromEditText() {


    localHolder = ed_local.getText().toString().trim();
    direccionHolder = ed_direccion.getText().toString().trim();
    telHolder = ed_tel.getText().toString().trim();
    longitudHolder = ed_longitud.getText().toString().trim();
    latitudHolder = ed_latitud.getText().toString().trim();

}
```

}

MANIFEST

```
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo2"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".RegistroActivity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: El problema no son los permisos de Android. Esto se debe a las reglas que hayas definido en Firebase para escribir en los nodos. Revisa las reglas y la documentación de Firebase acerca de ellas.

Comment: el problema que tenia es que el JSON estaba configurdo con otra app, lo que hice fue descargarlo con mi proyecto actual y funciono